# Copy and paste windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have been using windows 7 for some time now and have always used copy and paste etc without a problem.  I now highlight a section to copy but have to left click on my mouse to keep the highlighted area.  If I don't do this the whole is page is highlighted and I cannot copy.  Have I changed some settings for this to happen?

Would appreciate some help.

Thank you
Lorraine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check if your sticky key settings are not changed. Press shift 5 times continuously, a dialogue box with sticky key settings will appear. Disable it. and then check. Do this with both Shift keys.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to post your answer.  My problem is now sorted out.  Much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome, What was the solution ?

Comment: I followed your instruction by disabling the sticky key then enabled it as it did not work.  Somehow this solved the problem as I can now highlight copy/cut/paste without having to left click on the mouse.

Comment: Great.... You may vote the answer if you think it helped. This would help others as well.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but how do I vote.  This is the first time I've used this site...sorry!

Comment: Don't be, whenever you find any answer useful for you, you may vote for it as it helps other members to filter the best answer among many. Enjoy the journey at superuser. Keep helping others too